# Django serializer possibility of either creating new object or using an existing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Below is an example input:

```
'abc_obj': {
    "comments": string,
    "ref": string,
    "customer": 1,
    "address": {
        "street": string,
        "country": string,
    }
}
```

This is the serializer:

```
class ABCObjSerializer(ModelSerializer[ABCObj]):
    address: AddressSerializer = AddressSerializer(required=False)
    customer: CustomerSerializer = CustomerSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ABCObj
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "created_by": {"read_only": True},
        }
```

Is it possible with the existing serializer that I reuse / link the customer with the `id=1`. And in the next request if there is customer data (like address data in this request) then I create a new customer.

The purpose is to enable the user to either create a new record or use an existing one.

### Edit

Adding view:

```
class ABCObjViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = (
        ABCObj.objects.all()
        .select_related("customer", "delivery_address")
    )

    def get_serializer_class(self) -> Type[BaseSerializer[_MT_co]]:
        if hasattr(self, "action"):
            if self.action == "list":
                return SalesOrderListSerializer
            else:
                return ABCObjSerializer
```

Comment: Are you asking how to have a sort of "create or update" method? And basing that if there is an existing object for a given ID?

Comment: Can you post the relevant viewset code please?

Comment: hi @Swift I added the view which is a simple modelviewset. Actually its just a create. The model has some foreign keys. The user can either provide an id for the foreign keys or provide data for the related objects (In which case new related objects will be created).